# svg: stop inner groups from being rotating when the outer container is rotated

Tags: svg, d3.js

I' facing a case, where i have a container svg element and a set of inner sub-elements:

```
<g transform="translate(-157.82326597222223, 381.00000000000006),  rotate(180)">
   <path d="M 0 10  L 600 10 L 680 63.5 L 600 117 L 0 117 Z"></path>
   <g transform="translate(180, 35.099999999999994)">
        <foreignObject width="240" height="46.800000000000004">
           <body>
               <div style="font-size: 19.400000000000002px; text-align: center;">xxxx
               <br>2<br>
               </div>
           </body>
       </foreignObject>
   </g>
</g>
```

The problem is that when i rotate the main g, all the child elements are also rotated, which is reaonable of cource. I just want to know if there is a way to prevent some of the inner child elements from being rotated. So in my example, i don't want the foreignObject to be rotated, because it contains some text

Comment: Could you apply the reverse rotation to the inner object?

Comment: Well that's what i ended up doing, but it doesn't feel to me natural. It's like doing a double work

Comment: Miah's solution is the only way.  There is no way in SVG to exempt a child from its parent's transform.  The obvious question is then why is it part of the group if you don't want it to be included in the rotation?  Move it out of the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of absolute positioning in svg, an objects coordinante system is always based upon its parents. So in this instance, when you transformed and rotated the g object, it set up a new coordinate system whose origin was offset from the document origin by (-157.82326597222223, 381.00000000000006) and rotated by 180 degrees, and this new coordinate system is inherited by all of its children.

So it isn't really that the object underneath the first `<g>` are rotated, so much as the coordinate system that they are drawn onto are rotated compared to the global coordinate system.